# Using TeXMaker on Mac and Windows simultaneously

Tags: miktex, texmaker, mactex

I'm a LaTeX novice so forgive my ignorance. I would greatly appreciate any help with an issue I am having.

I created a basic template for my university reports and projects, on  my Mac laptop, with TeXMaker which makes use of MacTeX. I have recently acquired a desktop at home and would like to use this in conjunction with my Mac, however it doesn't seem to recognise the packages. I've loaded MikTeX and TeXMaker.

Is this a compatibility issue between MacTeX and MikTeX? Is there another Windows program I can make use of? Or any other method I could use to ensure editing on both my Mac and Windows operating systems?

Comment: Miktex comes in a minimal version and is suppose to install packages when they are needed. Since MacTeX is based on TeXLive, which is also available for Windows. I'd recommend removing miktex and installing TeXLive instead. Yes it is quite big, but as long as the editions (year) is the same for TeXLive and MacTeX, then you will have the same packages on both systems.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Launch "MiKTeX Options (Admin)" and check if "Install missing packages on-the-fly" is set to Yes

[image]

When you compile your document, MiKTeX will ask you to grant admin rights, answer Yes and your missing packages will install automatically.

Comment: thank you for your response. My computer had security restrictions which prevented  MiKTeX installing packages on-the-fly. When these security measured where bypassed it ran perfectly.